# Lost character while changing attribute of an object

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm relatively new to javascript and I've found a very strange thing happening on my program, might be something very stupid but I can't figure it out.

So here's the thing I have an svg rect that has some attributes:

```
var rectFiltres = 
groups.selectAll("rect")
.data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class","rect")
.attr({
    x: function(d){return 0},
    y: function(d){return 0},
    width : function(d){return 0},
    height : function(d){return 10},
    id : function (d){d.config;}


})
.style("fill",function(d){return color(d.combi)})
```

At some point in my script I'm trying to change the attribute "id" for multiple "rect" in a loop :

```
    for (var i=0;i<(confiClick.length-1);i++){

            var rectTest = d3.select(rectFiltres[0][i]);

            console.log(confiClick[i])

            var configIdRect = confiClick[i];

            console.log(configIdRect)
            rectTest.transition()
            .duration(800).style("opacity", 0.5)
            .attr("height",10)
            .attr("width",10)
            .attr("x",function(d){return largeurBox + confiClick[i].textWidth('arial',12)-20;})
            .attr("y",function(d){return haut2 +20*(i+1)-39;})
            .attr("id",configIdRect)
            .style("fill",colorBoxSelect)
            .style("opacity",0.5)

            console.log(rectTest)
        }
```

It worked fine almost every time, unless one time where a 0 in confiClick[0] which happen to disappear : confiClick[0] = "parc_client = TPH03" is stored in the rect as "parc_client = TPH3". 
The 0 has disappeared !! And I don't understand why.

[Here is the log in firefox, for some reason I can't try on another browser (job related issues)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOd9U.png)

This only happens in the first element of the loop and only for that values of the string which didn't help me understand the problem. (If this string is in the second or third position in the loop it works just fine)

I'd love to try any suggestion you may have because I'm kind of stuck with that one :/